# Inserting Smart DNS in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

How do I insert my Smart DNS numbers into Network Settings in 14.04 LTS. I have the IP address and the Gateway. I do not understand the way it has been explained before using terminal. Thanks.